# Scraping page with BS in python only captures first column of splitColumn

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the last part of [this](https://www.triodos.com/en/investment-management/socially-responsible-investment/sustainable-investment-universe/companies-atmf1/) page through BeautifulSoup in python.

I want to retrieve all the companies listed in the bottom. Furthermore, the companies are ordered alphabetically, where the companies with titles starting with "A-F" appear under the first tab, then "G-N" under the second tab and so on. You have to click the tabs for the names to appear, so I'll loop through the different "name pages" and apply the same code.

I'm having trouble retrieving all the names of a single page, however. 
When looking at the companies named "A-F" I can only retrieve the names of the first column of the table.

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
import requests

incl_page_url = "https://www.triodos.com/en/investment-management/socially-
responsible-investment/sustainable-investment-universe/companies-atmf1/"
page = requests.get(incl_page_url)
soup = Soup(page.content, "html.parser")

for header in soup.find("h2").next_siblings:
    try:
        for a in header.childGenerator():
            if str(type(a)) == "<class 'bs4.element.NavigableString'>":
                print(str(a))
    except:
        pass
```

As can be seen by running this, I only get the names from the first column.
Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot and tell me this is not what you wanted:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

incl_page_url = "https://www.triodos.com/en/investment-management/socially-responsible-investment/sustainable-investment-universe/companies-atmf1/"
page = requests.get(incl_page_url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "lxml")
for items in soup.select(".splitColumn p"):
    title = '\n'.join([item for item in items.strings])
    print(title)
```

Result:

```
3iGroup
8point3 Energy Partners  
A
ABN AMRO
Accell Group
Accsys Technologies
Achmea
Acuity Brands
Adecco
Adidas
Adobe Systems
```

Comment: I like it, but it only seems to return the first company under each letter. Can you somehow extract all companies instead?

Comment: That is how i created it. I thought you only need the first company under each letter. What is your expected output actually?

Comment: I've edited the code. Execute it and let me know if it still doesn't meet your requirement.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - but thanks! It works perfectly.